# Complex Base and Complex Power Question

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ when $a=b=0$ does not occur.

Thus, $(a+bi)^{(c+di)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{-d(\arctan2(a,b)+2\pi k)}(\cos(c\cdot (\arctan2(a, b)+2\pi k)+d\cdot \ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})+i \sin(c\cdot (\arctan2(a,b)+2\pi k)+d\cdot \ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}))$.

The square roots are principal roots. Do the natural logs have to yield non negative real values? I know computing cosine and sine of complex numbers is possible, but I am unsure of whether or not the natural logs have to be non negative real numbers for this situation.

Comment: What does $\arctan 2(a,b)$ mean?

Comment: I see it commonly written as $\theta$. Particularly in regards to a as the value for x and b as the value for y. Does that make sense or should I explain more?

Comment: Hmm. I'm familiar with the notation $arg(z)$, for the "argument", or angle of the complex number $z$. Is that what you mean? Which part of your notation means that: just the $(ab)$, or the whole $\arctan$ expression?

Comment: In particular, I've seen this: if $z=a+bi$, then $arg(z)=\arctan\frac{b}{a}$.

Comment: That's what I am saying. I am just writing it differently. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there's not just one way to define the natural logarithm function on $\mathbb{C}$, which means that complex exponentiation is also defined in different ways, depending on the choice of natural log. We generally write $z^w=\exp(w\log z)$, writing "log" for "ln" (because it seems that very few people working in complex variables write "ln"). How do we define $\log z$? Well, it has to satisfy the equation $e^{\log z}=z$, and no such function can be continuous on the whole complex plane. One common choice is to place the discontinuity along the negative real axis, so that the range of $\log$ is the strip of the plane with $-\pi<\mathcal{Im}(z)\leq \pi$. In that case, the logarithm of a positive real number is a positive real number.

In your expression, you have $\log\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, for which none of these questions really need to arise. Since $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then $a^2+b^2$ is a non-negative real number, it square root is a non-negative real number, and as long as it isn't $0$, the logarithm of that square root is a real number.